# How to disable right click event( with Inspect Element) in a webpage using CSS Without Script

Tags: html, css

*How to disable right click event( with Inspect Element) in a webpage using CSS Without Script.Using Below Code i got Output but it is script.So i need disabling event using CSS .Can anyone please let me know the answer.*

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: You can not prevent me from inspecting your code, if that’s what you’re asking … And preventing the context menu from working dramatically decreases usability.

Comment: CBroe if i  Disable Javascript in my webbrowser right click event should not work.

Comment: Why? To what purpose? What is the terrible thing that would happen, if the user was able to use their context menu?

Comment: CBroe,we provided some pdf and video (important content) in website.no one shoudn't download that.so that's why we need it.

Comment: Hiding Context menu can not stop people from downloading it :)

Comment: User can still open the developer tools from menu. You maybe could do this by adding a plugin to the user's browser, but even then one can simply wget and look at your code. Whatever you're trying to do, it's fake security. You should do your security on the server side instead of trusting the user and hoping for the best

Answer (score 0):

with css i think its not possible

add `oncontextmenu="return false"` to body tag in html page it should work

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
   .....
</body>
```

if you want to disable selection

```
body{
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Rahul Thanks For Replying.I tried this one also.But i didn't get Output.

Comment: by implementing above code you cant right click on your page + text selection is also disable

Comment: however you can press f12 and inspect element will get open

Comment: Rahul What u sent Code is Fine.But if u disable script in Content Settings everyone can get inspect Element.my requirement is i wouldn't like to open inspect element.

Comment: well I never mention its full proof, and you cant block access to inspect element completely, I suggest you should better focus on your code